# How to reset the terminal before command execution?

Tags: terminal, bash

I've been looking at spicing up my Terminal experience by among other things, adding some color. I used the `tput` command to build a nicely looking prompt. This is part of my `.bash_profile`:

```
BLACK=$(tput setaf 0)
RED=$(tput setaf 1)
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
BLUE=$(tput setaf 4)
MAGENTA=$(tput setaf 5)
CYAN=$(tput setaf 6)
WHITE=$(tput setaf 7)
BOLD=$(tput bold)
REVERSE=$(tput rev)
RESET=$(tput sgr0)

export PS1="${WHITE}$(date "+%H:%M") ${MAGENTA}\u${WHITE}@${MAGENTA}$(scutil --get ComputerName)${WHITE}:${MAGENTA}\w\n${GREEN}\$ ${REVERSE}"
```

Notice the ${REVERSE} (or `$(tput rev)`) at the end of the prompt, which makes the commands I type stand out by adding a background color.

[image]

My problem however is, that when executing any command, the style is not automatically reset upon pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, which in this case adds an undesired green background to the command's output as well. How can I reset the terminal right before command execution?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for in BASH is equivalant to what is built-in `precmd` in ZSH. This built-in function would be executed prior to executing a command. A work around is mentioned in https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command. I hope it gives you a hint of how to solve your problem. The reset has to be called within this function.

Comment: Thank you, this led me to adding `trap "tput sgr0" DEBUG`, which amazingly enough seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `reset` command (available at `/usr/bin/reset`) or `tput reset`.

Adding `${RESET}` at the end of the prompt seems to work.

Comment: Oh, you want to reset the terminal *right before* command execution but *after* typing the command. I don't know how to do that.